# How to create a navigation layout with a page that already has tabs?

Tags: navigation, tabs

One of my webpages has two tabs that the user can navigate between.  The tabs don't link to other webpages, but rather two different views inside the webpage, each with it's own set of questions the user can answer.  My site also involves two other pages.  One page allows them to begin answering the questions (by creating their own instance of the question page), and one page to allow them to view all active pages they have created.

The two tabs I mentioned are what is causing the design issue.  Currently, there is no link between the create page and the page where a user cna view all their active questions.  Even though we send an email to the user when they create their questionnaire instance with a link to the summary page, there is no way to naviagte between them, other than manually entering the URL in the address bar.  The only way I can think of adding in a feature cleanly is by making tabs, but I already have tabs with a different purpose specifically on one page.

What would be a good alternative to tabs for navigating between webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand

You have two tabs where users do their work.

```
+-------+ +-------+
| TAB 1 | | TAB 2 |
+-------+ +-------+
```

And now you need users to navigate between the pages? How about a main nav section?

It's done all the time. :-)

```
+----------------------------------+
| Main Nav                         |
+----------------------------------+
+-------+ +-------+
| TAB 1 | | TAB 2 |
+-------+ +-------+
```

Add some elements regarding where the user is in the process and the appropriate other information and you're done.

I'll edit this post with more information if necessary. I couldn't format the answer in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's pretty much how my page is displayed. I just feel like overloading a user with too many tabs isn't very clean.  I'm also a computer engineer, so what do I know about design :D.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Two tabs and navigation can look very clean and understandable or very cluttered depending on ... many, many variables. But, taken out of context, there's no reason not to have many tabs along with more than one navigation area.